# In tomcat 8, How to provide file path in setenv.bat to read from java class

Tags: java, file, tomcat, kerberos, setenv

I want to have my custom `java.security.auth.login.config` property to be read from a user defined file from tomcat directory say `TOMCAT_HOME/bin/jass.config`.

:: Settings in `setenv.bat` ::

```sh
set "jaasFile=C:\Users\...\apache-tomcat-8.5.33\bin\jass.conf"
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config=%jaasFile%"
```

however if I am reading it from java class is shows as **null** :

```java
System.getProperty("java.security.auth.login.config");  //  Showing as null
```

any hint how to achieve this?

Comment: The `set "CATALINA_OPTS...` line is missing a closing double quote `"` in you question (and maybe the `setenv.bat` file).

Comment: Double quote is already there  :                                                                                   
set "jaasFile=C:\Users\....\apache-tomcat-8.5.33\authabc\jass.conf"
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config=%jaasFile%"

Comment: It should be `set jaasFile="...."` and `set CATALINA_OPTS="...."`

Comment: Below is my setting in setenv.bat file ::
set jaasFile="C:\Users\...\jaas.conf"
set CATALINA_OPTS="%CATALINA_OPTS%-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%jaasFile%"
but still no luck...

Comment: Just to make sure: you are starting Tomcat using `catalina.bat/startup.bat`? Or are you starting Tomcat as a service (procrun)?

Comment: I am starting Tomcat as a service which is integrated with Eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setenv.bat` batch file is only sourced by the `*.bat` files distributed with Tomcat. No other method of starting the server uses that file.

If you start Tomcat from Eclipse, you can edit the JVM parameters and environment variables in the server's configuration page: double-click or hit `F3` on the server in the *"Servers"* view to open its *"Overview"* page, then click on *"Open launch configuration"*.

If you start Tomcat as a window service, open the [Procrun monitor application](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) (renamed to `tomcat8w.exe` in Tomcat's installation directory) and set the values there.

[image]

Comment: By setting JVM parameters in Eclipse I was able to get the values by using System.setProperty() in java class.;
I was really fighting to get this. Much appreciate !!